# Display message when "back" button is pressed (PHP or JS?)

Tags: php, javascript

I'm writing a PHP script and would like to present a warning message if the user clicks the back button on the browser.  **Is this something I can do in PHP?**  The only solution I've been able to find is via javascript, however it presents a warning message *every time something is submitted* on the page. If there is not a way to do this in PHP, can this javascript be altered to only work when the back button is pressed on the browser?  Thanks.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" defer="defer">
 window.onbeforeunload = eventTermination;
 function eventTermination(args) {
 args.returnValue = ('WARNING:CANNOT GO BACK');
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: You might want to look at the [jQuery history plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/#) and the [onhashchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange)

Comment: If anyone views this in the future, this question helped me find my solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263583/implement-a-back-button-warning-in-javascript-for-use-in-flex

Comment: There are many ways of navigating back without pressing the back button, such as alt+left cursor, gestures, backspace key, etc. Onbeforeunload will fire whenever the user leaves the page, not just when they go back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use PHP for this as PHP is a server-side scripting, means that the script is compiled on the server and sent to the client broswer as a HTML file.

But JS is a client-side script, which means that it is compiled on browser side (client side).

So for your request, PHP is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in PHP

use javascript or jquery

PHP is a server side scripting language and javascript is a client side scripting language, so the concept of alert box is only given in javascript not in php.